# How can I generate a range of random floating point numbers in Julia?

Tags: random, julia

I noticed that `rand(x)` where `x` is an integer gives me an array of random floating points. I want to know how I can generate an array of random float type variables within a certain range. I tried using a range as follows:

```
rand(.4:.6, 5, 5)
```

And I get:

```
 0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4
 0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4
 0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4
 0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4
 0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4
```

How can I get a range instead of the lowest number in the range?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Perhaps a bit more elegant, as you actually want to sample from a Uniform distribution, you can use the `Distributions` package:

```
julia> using Distributions
julia> rand(Uniform(0.4,0.6),5,5)
5×5 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.547602  0.513855  0.414453  0.511282  0.550517
 0.575946  0.520085  0.564056  0.478139  0.48139
 0.409698  0.596125  0.477438  0.53572   0.445147
 0.567152  0.585673  0.53824   0.597792  0.594287
 0.549916  0.56659   0.502528  0.550121  0.554276
```

The same method then applies from sampling from other well-known or user-defined distributions (just give the distribution as the first parameter to `rand()`)

Answer (score 8):

You need a step parameter:

```
rand(.4:.1:.6, 5, 5)
```

The `.1` will provide a step for your range which is necessary for floating point numbers and not necessary for incrementing by 1. The issue is that it will assume 1 regardless of implicit precision. If you need the increment more precise than do the following:

```
rand(.4:.0001:.6, 5, 5)
```

This will give you a result that looks similar to:

```
 0.4587  0.557   0.586   0.4541  0.4686
 0.4545  0.4789  0.4921  0.4451  0.4212
 0.4373  0.5056  0.4229  0.5167  0.5504
 0.5494  0.4068  0.5316  0.4378  0.5495
 0.4368  0.4384  0.5265  0.5995  0.5231
```

Comment: I like how this highlights the initial problem with your code but the other answer actually gives the recommended way of doing it.

Comment: You can also use `eps()` as the step parameter, which is approximately `2.220446049250313e-16`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with

```
julia> map(x->0.4+x*(0.6-0.4),rand(5,5))
5×5 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.455445  0.475007  0.518734  0.463064  0.400925
 0.509436  0.527338  0.566976  0.482812  0.501817
 0.405967  0.563425  0.574607  0.502343  0.483075
 0.50317   0.482894  0.54584   0.594157  0.528844
 0.50418   0.515788  0.5554    0.580199  0.505396
```

The general rule is

```
julia> map(  x -> start + x * (stop - start), rand(5,5)  )
```

where start is 0.4  and stop is 0.6

You can even generate a six sided dice this way by having x ranging from 1 to 7 that is 1 < x < 7 since the probability of x being exactly 1.0 or 7.0 is zero

```
julia> map(x->Integer(floor(1+x*(7-1))),rand(5,5))
5×5 Array{Int64,2}:
 2  6  6  3  2
 3  1  3  1  6
 5  4  6  1  5
 3  6  5  5  3
 3  4  3  5  4
```

or you can use

```
julia> rand(1:6,5,5)
5×5 Array{Int64,2}:
 3  6  3  5  5
 2  1  3  3  3
 1  5  4  1  5
 5  5  5  5  1
 3  2  1  5  6
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another simple solution (using vectorized operations)

```
0.2 .* rand(5,5) .+ 0.4
```

And if efficiency matters...

```
@time 0.2 .* rand(10000, 10000) .+ 0.4
>> 0.798906 seconds (4 allocations: 1.490 GiB, 5.20% gc time)

@time map(x -> 0.4 + x * (0.6 - 0.4), rand(10000, 10000))
>> 0.836322 seconds (49.20 k allocations: 1.493 GiB, 7.08% gc time)

using Distributions 
@time rand(Uniform(0.4, 0.6), 10000, 10000)
>> 1.310401 seconds (2 allocations: 762.940 MiB, 1.51% gc time)

@time rand(0.2:0.000001:0.4, 10000, 10000)
>> 1.715034 seconds (2 allocations: 762.940 MiB, 6.24% gc time)
```